# Saving a file without downloading JS

Tags: javascript, html

How to create a file (PHP), add some code and save it in the same directory of the HTML/PHP file **{Using JS;}**
I don't want the PHP file to be downloaded or be shown in a blob
I want it to happen as a backend process **(Non-Visible)**

Comment: You want to save a file serverside, using JS, on a PHP server? I think you may need to clarify the question.

Comment: Use the `file_put_contents()` function to have `PHP` write a file on the server. The browser isn't involved.

Comment: Actually I'm a beginner developer. What I want to do is, I will run a js script and it should create a new file with some code and save it in the directory (in the website's files folder) (I'm doing it live with 000wehostapp)  Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, running on the browser (and I assume that is the case here because you also talk about using PHP) has no way to write to the server's file system.

Imagine if you could open the Console in your browser's developer tools, run a script, and write arbitrary data to a file on your choice on google.com, or your online banking. Bad, right?

The only ways that browser-side JS can interact with the server are via HTTP requests and websockets (which aren't relevant for the rest of this answer).

If you want to store data on the server, then you need to make an HTTP request (e.g. [using `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)) to some server-side code and then have that server side code store it.

With PHP you can write files with [`file_put_contents`](https://php.net/file_put_contents) (although you need to be careful about file permissions and the possibility of multiple processes trying to write to the same file at one (see [file locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking)).

Generally speaking, if you want to write to a file on the server then in *almost* **every** circumstance you should be using a database and not writing directly to the file system.